# Word 2010: Remove space before citation

Tags: microsoft-word, whitespace, citations

When I insert a citation into my document (testing with the IEEE 2006 style here), I end up with something like this:

```
This is some text ( [1], [2])
```

As you can see Word 2010 adds a space between  the [1] and the left parenthesis. And here's an example: http://iru.ch/stackexchg/citation_test.docx

*How can I get rid of the whitespace between the left parenthesis and the citation?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer and workaround [in the forums](https://web.archive.org/web/20110817082635/http://bibword.codeplex.com/discussions/69286) of the excellent BibWord project. From user [maha78](https://web.archive.org/web/20110817042239/http://www.codeplex.com:80/site/users/view/maha78):

> I found the leading space only occured if I tried to insert a citation between pre-existing parertheses, for example. However, if I inserted the citation first and then put paretheses around it no leading space appeared.

Other solutions include converting all citations to static text or using Word's "Design Mode". In all cases,
refreshing all citations (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>)
doesn't work or adds the space again.

Comment: This still somewhat works in Word 2017. Unfortunately, if you insert the parentheses afterwards and update the reference, it will again insert the space.